# Jquery removing ' ' from create element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In this code i want to create a new span element, which i already took the text from previous page:

```
(function (global) {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    var text = document.createTextNode(global.localStorage.getItem("mySharedData"));
    span.appendChild(text);
    document.body.appendChild(span);
    }(window));
```

And I want to remove the " from: (the var text value)

```
<span>
      "<b>My contents are from <u><span style="color:rgb(0, 148, 133);">SPAN</span></u></b>"
</span>
```

How to remove the " in the beginning of the text and the " in the end of text.
How could i trim the " ?

Previously i tried creating an existing span with id which i want to only replace the text but the same problem existing which " " make it unable to be read.

```
<span id="something">text</span>
```

Update:
I don't know if this is a dirty workaround or what, but somehow i could make it works with: (even though it's not perfect yet)

```
<span id="output"></span>
<script>
(function (global) {
    var oldHTML = document.getElementById('output').innerHTML;
    var newHTML = oldHTML + global.localStorage.getItem("mySharedData");
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = newHTML;
    }(window));
</script>
```

Comment: Where does the content come from? How did you save it on the previous page?

Comment: I use this to save it from previous page:
(function (global) {
    document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function () {
        global.localStorage.setItem("mySharedData", text);
    }, false);
}(window));

where text is the variable containing text= $("#input").val();

Comment: Isn't the solution to remove the " from the item in the local storage? What populates the localStorage? Make your fix there, not where your attempting to fix it

Comment: Maybe yes, but then if we got long text it would be doing the same thing again with the " problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `innerHTML` of a `span`:

```
(function (global) {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerHTML = global.localStorage.getItem("mySharedData");
    document.body.appendChild(span);
    }(window));
```

example: https://jsbin.com/bahikunuxo/edit?js,output

**P.S.** `document.createTextNode` returns html encoded text:

```
document.createTextNode('<span></span>');
//return &lt;span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;
//but browser inspect element shows it as: "<span></span>"
```

Comment: So far the first " has been passed but then it's becoming
 <span>
  <b>
    "My contents are from "
      <u>
        <span style="color:rgb(0,148,133);">SPAN</span>
      </u>
  </b>
</span>

Comment: @Mukyuu do you see that when inspect element or in browser output?

Comment: when inspecting. on output the span got separated by boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Your can use `slice` for this as follows:

```
(function (global) {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    var localStorageText = global.localStorage.getItem("mySharedData");
    var textToShow = localStorageText.slice(1, -1); 
    var text = document.createTextNode(textToShow);
    span.appendChild(text);
    document.body.appendChild(span);
}(window));
```

Hope this help!

Comment: I wouldn't slice on the text node. I would do it on the actual text from localstorage and then create the text node.

Comment: No. You made it worse :) It makes no sense now. You're not adding the textnode to the DOM, just the text.

Comment: @Apb: the slice cut down the < and the > :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove them, you can simply run a `replace` on the string like so. This can cause issues if you have quotes in the middle, otherwise you can just substring.

```
span.textContent.replace(/["]/g, "");
```

I suggest using the substring method like below on the element:

```
span.textContent.slice(1, -1);
```

Comment: That first one is no good because it will remove other quotes.

Comment: @Andy that's why I disclaimed that would cause issues if there are more quotes. Thanks Ashley, got it.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that before the example code, not after. Because all I saw was that the example was no good and didn't read further.